# Getting Notification for WFP User-Mode Filter

Tags: windows, networking, driver, wfp

WFP supports adding filters through the user-mode API. My question is how can the app that adds such filter get notified when the filter action is applied. For example, if it wants to log connection blocked by the filters, etc. This is easy to achieve in kernel where the callouts can do that, but I don't see how it could be done in the user-mode.

Thanks in advance.

G.